# How can store multidimension array in django python

Tags: python, django

I have two dictionaries which i want to compare the values. Like

```
Dict1['var1'] = 20
Dict1['var2'] = 30

Dict2['var1'] = 23
Dict2['var1'] = 26
```

Now i want to copare them and store the result like true or false in the same dict like this

```
if (Dict1['var1']  < Dict2['var1'])
   Dict2['var1']['result'] = true
```

Becasue in my django template i want to show the color of table row as green if the result is true.

Whats the best way i can do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `Dict2['var1']` is assigned as int type, the `Dict2['var1']['result']` cannot be a dict type.

You can try this:

```
Dict1['var1'] = {'value':20, 'result':None}
Dict1['var2'] = {'value':30, 'result':None}
Dict2['var1'] = {'value':23, 'result':None}
Dict2['var2'] = {'value':26, 'result':None}


if Dict1['var1']['value']  < Dict2['var1']['value']:
    Dict2['var1']['result'] = True
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are want to check and decide in django template, you do not need to pre-compare and store the result. You can directly compare them in template itself.

```
{%if Dict1.var1 < Dict2.var1 %}
   {# render to show green #}
{%else%}
   {# do something else #}
{%endif}%
```